# Search box does not float right

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have created expandable search box and  set it to "float:left".

But Moving  "float:right" for a search box. -  https://www.screencast.com/t/mZ5LpKkjH1O

You can see this in action at http://www.test3.guru99.com/

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - external links are discouraged as they can change over time and are not helpful to other users. (Also, many people are understandably wary of clicking random unknown links). See: [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Add float:left!important; for class="maximenuck maximenuckmodule item1509 last level1 ". Refer below image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXaug.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating right the search box element, float right its container, in this case the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 way according to your requirements.

1. Make background-position: right center. It'll help to looking animation from right to left.
2. If you really want animation from right to left so you have to make search box as an overlay(in this case search box will overlap with menu) by position:absolute and it'll stick first time in same position and after click it'll expand to left and overlap with menu.

and as per your website, you just have to fix width like 50px of parent `li` tag of search-box.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you please provide me any screenshot or exmplae.

Comment: @TusharKorat its up to *you* to provide *us* with an example of the issue you are having. You need to give us the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can show you exactly how to fix it.